# Jade Template load function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have problem with loading function from outside script.
Here is my code:

**page.jade**

```
doctype
html
head
  script(src="/script.js")
body
 -if( isGuest() )
    //do something
```

**script.js**

```
function isGuest(){
 return getCookie("token");
}
```

When I load this its give me error
"undefined is not a function"

Comment: Where is `getCookie` is defined? AND FYI: You are doing it wrong. Jade uses its own template variables not the JavaScript ones.

Comment: You should pass `token` as `locals` to Jade ([doc](http://jade-lang.com/api/). Jade can't access browser's JavaScript environment directly.